# Как создать интерфейс Java

Tags: java, android

Как создать интерфейс как на фото.

А именно что и где нужно нажать и выбрать чтобы создать файл интерфейса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда создаете класс, там выпадает меню, где можно выбрать что это будет. В вашем случае - интерфейс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПКМ по имени пакета -> New -> Java Class -> Interface

[image: 1]

[image: 2]